# How far is AI from making movies just by using script or description like we use for generating images in midjourney or DALL-E etc

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, generative-model, gpt

I'm curious about the current state of AI technology when it comes to generating movies from textual descriptions. I'm aware of impressive advancements in generating images using models like Midjourney and DALL-E, but I'm wondering if similar progress has been made in the domain of movie production.

Specifically, I'm interested to know if there are existing technologies that can take a script or a detailed description and generate a full-length movie, including visuals, audio, and potentially even dialogues. If such technology exists, I would appreciate any insights into its capabilities and limitations.

Alternatively, if there are no known solutions that can accomplish this task, I would like to understand the current state of research and development in this area. Are there any ongoing projects or promising approaches that are bringing us closer to the goal of generating movies solely from text inputs?

Comment: Very very far. Even image generation requires a lot of try or tunes to get a good result when you expect something specific (less now with the use of ControlNet however). In order to make a movie, it's more realistic that some AI would be able to make really small videos of a few seconds or minutes and you will have to design hundreds of them and concatenate them to make your film. You would also need different AI models for the audio etc.